# bash nested for loop not working

Tags: bash

I've written a bash script to ban country IP blocks from my router.

Why is it that the following works:

```
for ip in $(wget -qO- http://ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/cn.zone)
do 
    iptables -I wanin -s "$ip" -j DROP
done
```

But the following in which I nest multiple countries does not?

```
for country in CN AD
do 
    for ip in $(wget -qO- http://ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/$country.zone) 
    do 
        iptables -I wanin -s "$ip" -j DROP
    done
done
```

Answer (score 3):

See that it's case sensistive. You have

```
for country in CN AD;
```

See that you are using caps here. If you use

```
for country in cn ad;
```

Then it should work. Try out yourself the link [not working upper case zone](http://ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/CN.zone) and [working with lower case zone](http://ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/cn.zone)

Answer (score 1):

Since `country` is expected to be lowercase you may add `declare -l country` like this:

```
declare -l country
for country in CN AD; do 
  for ip in $(wget -qO- http://ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/$country.zone); do
    iptables -I wanin -s "$ip" -j DROP
  done
done
```

or use the [`${var,,}` parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
for country in CN AD; do 
  for ip in $(wget -qO- http://ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/${country,,}.zone); do
    iptables -I wanin -s "$ip" -j DROP
  done
done
```